# Setting variables in temp tables

Tags: mysql

Can anybody help on a problem I am having. For the software i am using it won't accept temp tables unless the table is created and inserted into just like i tried with this.

Before i put in the create table and insert into just the table it works fine but when i try this it says the table already exists.

Can anybody see what i am doing wrong and can advise, it's the variables in my temp tables that is throwing me off.

```
declare @bt_id varchar(20) = '110';         
declare @ms_id varchar(20) = '2';   
declare @sqlstr varchar(max) = '';




if object_id('tempdb..#measure_raw') is not null
drop table #measure_raw

        CREATE TABLE #measure_raw(
meas_id INT, 
column_name VARCHAR (255),  
vlu_txt VARCHAR (255),
batch_id INT,
row_num INT,
)

insert into #measure_raw

set @sqlstr = 'select det.meas_id,col.tbl_nm+''.''+col.logged_nm as column_name, det.vlu_txt, det.batch_id, '
            + 'case when (det.row_num is null) then 1 else det.row_num end as row_num '
            + 'into #measure_raw from detail_t det '
            + 'inner join column_t col on col.col_id=det.col_id inner join measure_t rul on rul.meas_id=det.meas_id '
            + 'where det.batch_id = ' + @bt_id + ' '

if @ms_id <> '0'
    set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'and det.meas_id = ' + @ms_id + ' '

set @sqlstr = @sqlstr + 'order by '
            + 'det.batch_id, det.meas_id, det.row_num, col.tbl_nm, col.logged_nm'

exec(@sqlstr)
```

Comment: MySQL or MSSQL? Your code is for MSSQL.

Comment: MySQL the code is for

Comment: So to answer your question: "Can anybody see what i am doing wrong": Well, as I already mentioned: the code you use is for mssql. It will not work in mysql. At all. You should get a bunch of other error messages. I'm not even sure how your code got to the create table part even with `continue on error`, since there is no  `;` after `drop table #measure_raw`. Look through any of the "related" questions on the right to get ideas on how to create temporary tables in mysql.